# How to parametrize test data while running appium automation scripts on multiple devices?

Tags: java, selenium, testng, appium

I am currently working on a mobile automation framework using Appium, java, and testng. The tests are supposed to run paralleled across multiple devices/emulators. But I want to send different test data for each thread. How can I achieve that? is it possible to send different test data to each thread through the testng xml file.

Thanks

Comment: I understood your question like this:
You have a test class with 10 test cases. You have 2 devices. You need to run all the 10 test cases for 2 devices with different set of data. So totally 20 test cases should run (10 test cases with set 1 data and 10 test cases with set 2 data). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes this is the exact case :)

Comment: Knowing that test cases will be executed on both devices at the same time